# "Expect" usage and subjunctive in English

Tags: word-usage, subjunctives

Can I write

> 1. "We expect from you that by the end of the program you would have learned to…"

or

> 2. "We expect from you that by the end of the program you will learn to…"

Thanks everybody. It seems that keeping the infinitive in the best By the end of the program we expect you to have learned _______ and then infinitive, Practical English Usage Michael Swan

Comment: The typical writing of this statement is "By the end of the program  we expect you to have learned _______

Comment: @tenthdoctor’s comment notwithstanding, I would write it as, “We expect that by the end of the program you ***will have learned*** to ...”

Comment: There is no subjunctive in your examples.

Answer (score 1):

The former is correct, however, the latter is incorrect.
Having said "you will learn to" subsequent to saying "by the end of the program" is not correct, as you have rendered the former phrase dependent on the latter and therefore it can precede the latter. Saying, "by the end..." specifies the following action should have already been completed therefore must be in the past tense. You could, however, say, "we expect from you that by the end of the program you will have learned to...."